# Change into intransitive form

Tags: verbs, て-form, particle-が, particle-を, passive-voice

How will the following sentence be written using intransitive verb. Will the verb 建てる use が or を

> うちの前に高いビルを建てました。

Will it be:

> うちの前に高いビル**が**建てられて日当たりが悪くなりました。

Or

> うちの前に高いビル**を**建てられて日当たりが悪くなりました。

Comment: related/duplicate: [How is the passive form used with を?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/69169/how-is-the-passive-form-used-with-%e3%82%92)

Comment: It could be either depending on if you want 日当たり or not.

Comment: 建てられる is the passive form of the transitive verb 建てる. The intransitive equivalent is 建つ.

Comment: @istrasci あ、確かに・・「向かいに巨大なスーパー**を**建てられて、買い物が便利になりました。」ってちょっとおかしいもんね。

Answer (score 3):

> How will the following sentence be written using intransitive verb.
> うちの前に高いビルを建てました。

The sentence literally means "(Someone) built a tall building in front of my house." It's missing the subject.

To use an intransitive verb, you can say:

> うちの前に高いビルが建ちました。
> "A tall building was built in front of my house."

建てる is transitive, and 建つ is intransitive.

> Will the verb 建てる use が or を

建てる takes a direct object. You can use 建てる this way:

「(人)が(物)を建てる」 -- "(Someone) builds (something)"

---

> Will it be:
> うちの前に高いビルが建てられて日当たりが悪くなりました。
> Or
> うちの前に高いビルを建てられて日当たりが悪くなりました。

The former is a normal passive sentence (Direct Passive). It's the passive sentence of 「(誰かが)うちの前に高いビルを建てて日当たりが...」

The latter is Indirect Passive (間接受身), or Suffering Passive (迷惑の受身).

Compare:

(誰かが)ビルを建てる -- Active "(Someone) builds a building"
ビルが(誰かに)建てられる -- Direct Passive "A building is built (by someone)"
(私が)(誰かに)ビルを建てられる -- Indirect Passive "(Someone) builds a building (*implying:* and it inconveniences me)."

For more on Suffering Passive:

- [How to interpret indirect passives?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15933/9831)
- https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1777/9831
- https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4947/9831